I encounter many errors (!) on requests for site speed evaluation and damaged previews
for a few days now, when I do speed tests, these errors always appear, sometimes on the mobile version, sometimes on the computer version. How come? why has this error been recurring lately. even if I delete the cache and try again nothing always error.. can you help me? thank you all for your attention.
Incomplete results, and often incorrect previews.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
